# How can I print keeping the theme colors? VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, printing, colors

I am trying to print code through the PrintCode extension but it does not keep the current theme colors that I am using. In addition, it makes the background white and I want it in black as in the dark mode

pls help!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the developers of the Print extension, only light themes are available for customization, as "printers use white paper". There is no way to export dark themed source code as PDFs unfortunately.

Source:
https://github.com/PDConSec/vsc-print/blob/HEAD/doc/manual.eng.md#printing-source-code